# BrowserWindow can not take over keyboard focus when hosted in wpf HwndSource

Tags: c#, wpf, electron

my wpf application hosts an electron window by HwndSource, all has been working for several years on electron 10.1.6, now following the docs `break changes` and try to upgrade to 20.3.0. changes only:

in main, `require('@electron/remote/main').initialize();`
in preload, `const remote = require('@electron/remote');`
when create BrowserWindow set `sandbox = false;` `contextIsolation = false;` `nodeIntegration = true;` and `require('@electron/remote/main').enable(win.webContents);`

then mouse click between wpf part and this electron window.
within 10.1.6, keyboard focus will jump between.
within 20.3.2, i can click any buttons in electron area, but can not input anything for its textbox, by snoop, i can see the keyboard focus always on wpf parent window. seems electron can not take keyboard focus from wpf window.

after BrowserWindow show, i have tried `wnd.focus();` `wnd.focusOnWebView();` `wnd.webContents.focus();` even call `blur()` first then `focus()`, or an addon extension that call win32 api `SetFocus(HWND)`, but no lucky.

any suggestion here? it blocks me now, also cannot google any helpful solution.

Comment: Try ask at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues.

Answer (score 0):

already workaround, no matter wpf or electron, they are win32 window, we can get its handle and monitor message, when `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` is coming and once if `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` detected then `SetFocus`.

```
    case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        SetFocus(hwnd);
    break;
```